# Panoramio placemarks I saved in Google Earth are broken; can they be fixed?

Tags: kml, google-earth

In Google Earth I have saved many Panoramio placemarks by right-clicking and selecting **Save to My Places**.  However these placemarks stopped working some time ago by which I mean that clicking one of them no longer loads an image.  On the Panoramio layer a placemark currently exists at the same location as each of these and those placemarks do load images.

It appears that the numeric identifier for each photo has changed.  For example an old, now broken placemark contains:

```
<body onload="loadPhotos(206837332,'000145',20,48.719844,-121.839747,'n')">
```

A new saved placemark for the same photo contains:

```
<body onload="loadPhotos(107693486,'000145',18,48.719844,-121.839747,'n')">
```

- Is there a way to remap the identifiers in my existing placemarks to the new ones?
- If not is there a way to look up photos by geographic coordinates (which as you can see are identical)?
- If I manage to fix these placemarks I would like to save the photos locally so that they do not break again.  Has anyone automated this process?

Comment: I don't think this is a too broad question. First two bullets seems to be mutually exclusive (thus, it makes a one question). The third one is a bonus (but it could be a consequence/method of answering the previous question). I suggest leaving it open.